# Why does reflected light not cancel out depending on color?

Tags: waves, visible-light, reflection

I have been learning about light reflection and refraction and  was thinking about objects reflecting only certain wave-lengths.
Why doesn't a red object with a green light shone on it appear black?

I know that some extra light would get in from surounding sources ans the colors might not be perfect opposites, but theoretically, why not?.

Answer (score 1):

They do! But for this effect to work, you need to *only* illuminate with red light. If you shine a green flashlight on a red object in a well lit room, there will still be red light from the white light of the illumination.

In the image below you see your exact scenario in the red hearts of the playing card under the green illumination.

Note that glossiness also plays a role. Any smooth surface will be reflective under large enough angles (Fresnel reflections). That's why the bell pepper has a white spot in the normally colored image and, likewise, a red spot in the red image.

[image]

source of image: https://micro.magnet.fsu.edu/optics/lightandcolor/primary.html